# Failing to shorten similar function calls using generics

Tags: c#, generics, types

I'm having huge problems with my code responsible for loading data from a database and converting it to lists of my custom data model objects.

As there are many data tables I'm going to have many Lists and I don't really want to create and assign them manually using copy/paste and just modifying the types.

Here is what I have for now, but there are errors displayed inside the `LoadAllModelListsAsProperties` method about failing conversions between `Type` and generic type parameters.

I can't figure out how get around this incompatibility of `Type` and `<T>`. What should I do?

```
public class DataProvider
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> Memory { get; set; }
    private static Dictionary<Type, Type> AllModelTypes { get; }


    static DataProvider()
    {
        AllModelTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        {
            { typeof(AreaModel),                typeof(Areas) },
            { typeof(GroupModel),               typeof(Groups) },
             /* many more.... */
            { typeof(TownModel),                typeof(Towns) }
        };
    }


    public DataProvider()
    {
        // fill Memory dictionary with empty list instances
        foreach (Type ModelType in AllModelTypes.Keys)
        {
            Memory.Add(ModelType, Activator.CreateInstance(
                                  typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(ModelType)));
        }
    }


    public List<TModel> GetModelList<TModel>(Type modelType)
        where TModel : ModelBase
    {
        // get the list from memory that matches the given type
        return (List<TModel>)Memory[modelType];
    }

    public void LoadAllModelListsAsProperties()
    {
        var filter = (c) => true;  // just simplified as example

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> item in AllModelTypes)
        {
            Type modelType = item.Key;
            Type linqType = item.Value;

            List<ModelBase> modelList = GetModelList<modelType>(modelType);
            // !!!! ^^^^^^ error that it can't implicitly convert
            //             List<modelType> to List<Modelbase>

            modelList.Clear();
            modelList.AddRange(LoadListOfModels<linqType, modelType>(filter, 
                                        modelType.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
            // !!!! ^^^^^^ error that "linqType"/"modelType" are variables,
            //             but get used like types; and that
            //             Type has no definition for "ModelFactoryFromLinq
        }

        // normally I would have to call something like that for every list type:
        //AreaModels = LoadListOfModels<Areas, AreaModel>(
        //    filter, AreaModel.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
        //GroupModels = LoadListOfModels<Groups, GroupModel>(
        //    filter, GroupModel.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
        //TownModels = LoadListOfModels<Towns, TownModel>(
        //    filter, TownModel.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
    }


    public List<TModel> LoadListOfModels<TLinq, TModel>(
        Func<TLinq, bool> filter,
        Func<TLinq, TModel> modelFactory
        )
        where TLinq : class, ILinqClass
        where TModel : ModelBase
    {
        using (LinqToSqlDataContext dc = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
        {
            return dc.GetTable<TLinq>()
                .Where(filter)
                .Select(modelFactory)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). However, I suggest that you encapsulate some of the logic in `LoadAllModelListsAsProperties` (the logic that applies to a single type) into a generic method. This way, you minimize the amount of reflection that you need to do.

Comment: What is `ModelFactoryFromLinq`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad That's a static method each model class has which returns a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use a type variable as type
2. You can use the Base class as type => `GetModelList<ModelBase>(modelType);`
3. You dont need to use type for method `LoadListOfModels` when you pass the correct objects to the method. The compiler will determine the generic type from the parameters.
4. What is ModelFactoryFromLinq? If it is a property, you just have to use reflection or you could create a method to return the correct func<..> via the given type. If it is a method try this:

   ```
       foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> item in AllModelTypes)
       {
           Type modelType = item.Key;
           Type linqType = item.Value;

           List<ModelBase> modelList = GetModelList<ModelBase>(modelType);
           // !!!! ^^^^^^ error that it can't implicitly convert
           //             List<modelType> to List<Modelbase>

           modelList.Clear();
           var ModelFactoryFromLinq = modelType.GetMethod("ModelFactoryFromLinq");
           modelList.AddRange(LoadListOfModels(filter, modelFactoryFromLinq));
           // !!!! ^^^^^^ error that "linqType"/"modelType" are variables,
           //             but get used like types; and that
           //             Type has no definition for "ModelFactoryFromLinq
       }
   ```